# Can you blow enemies heads off in the campaign?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war

I found an German soldier without a head on [Their Land, Their Blood](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Their_Land,_Their_Blood) level. I'm fairly sure I've killed the man as I was just firing at that position. I was holding a MG42 gun that can cause dismemberment (doesn't equal to severed heads, only limbs - losing a head must be extremely rare).
This is my second playthrough of the campaign and I can't recall seeing     something equivalent.

[image]
[image]

---

Heads constantly explode in separate zombies mode, the question is about the campaign.
[PC, Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/10090/).

Comment: When I played this year's ago, I don't ever recall heads being dismembered.  Is this PC or console  (which console if it is)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [video game gore website](https://web.archive.org/web/20171211022455/http://goretastic.com/cod.html) this is possible and World at War is the only Call of Duty game having head dismemberment (WW2 featured decapitation later in 2017).

From [Wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Gib):

> On occasion, **when enemy's head is blown off**, the enemy will shriek in
>   agony for a few seconds after, even without a mouth/head to scream
>   with.

Comment: Addendum: This is no longer true with COD:WW2's release

Comment: @PausePause: Thank you, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can (gruesome)!

I've successfully reproduced this multiple times on the same level, with the same gun, on PC (also Steam version).

When I played this years ago (as I stated in my comment), it was on the Xbox 360.  I'm wondering if the console versions did not have head dismemberment included.  I do remember limbs being dismembered from the console version however.